Creating a responsive Gomoku board with clickable squares
I am trying to create a gomoku board where users can click on the line intersections. I created this in Vue playground which works fine on a large screen size. However, when I shrink the width of the screen the squares suddenly no longer fit to the parent. I tried all kind of things with aspect ratios on a cell and on the grid parent but it just messed up the shape all together.
Basically I have 2 questions:

How can I make this grid look good on all screen sizes (down to say around 275px width of the board at least)?
Is there a simpler solution of doing this?


See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . This kind of questions isn't too specific for SO. It's up to you how you make it look "good". If you have problems with HTML/CSS layout then I'd suggest to make an example with static layout and ask specific questions about it, you can mention that it's a part of something else but at this point Vue looks totally irrelevant

@EstusFlask I have a specific question that my grid layout isn't holding to the 14x14 grid on smaller screen sizes. I am so sick of these kinds of feedback on SO, it makes people leave and not wanna ask questions. Sure, I added a 2nd question if there is simpler way of doing it, is that what is wrong??

This isn't just how problems are solved on SO, it wasn't specifically me who invented this. It's unknown what exactly is the problem with smaller sizes, you provided Vue-specific demo that doesn't work well with smaller screens, it's unclear if it's a part of the problem. You have HTML+CSS problem, and narrowing it down to Vue implementation seriously decreases your chances to get help to solve it. Would you prefer a series of downvotes with no explanation what you did wrong? I'd advise against using css grid here because it may not give enough control AND you don't really use its benefits

@EstusFlask I never said it is Vue specific, I said it is related to the grid layout. SO have become super snobbish, you can't ask anything without getting attacked, asked to close, or downvotet until eternity. Tell me again, what is wrong with this question? I gave example code, told you what I tried and also asked clear questions to what my problem is (clear to me as a non english native speaker at least). Tell me, because I am getting so sick of this on SO

The question has only vue tag and code is semi-intelligible for non-vue devs. If you ask layout guys then it won't help to give them vue code.  If you care about solving your problem then it's in your interests to do some work to make this possible. Please, check the link above. It needs clear problem statement (what exactly is wrong, with examples and a screenshot if it cannot be easily explained). Minimal code needs to be shown in the question, so it could be easily reproduced. These requirements exist not for the sake of snobbery but because this saves everyone's time and solves problems

try this
